# How to send model specific attributes to server side in extjs4?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am working in extjs4 MVC structure and I have been facing problem in extjs4 
all the fields are submitting to server side but I want to send only some fileds of model class to server side. How can I get this output?

1) Here is my model class

```
Ext.define('ab.model.sn.UserModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    //idproperty:'userId',//fields property first position pk. 
    fields: ['userId','firstName','middleName','lastName','languageId','primaryEmail','birthDate','password','securityQuestionId','securityQuestionAnswer','isMale','creationTime','ipAddress','confirmationCode','userStatusId',],
    proxy:
    {
        type:'ajax',
            //type:'localstorage',
            //id:'users',
        api:
        {
            read:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
            create:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin122',
            update:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin123'
        },//end of api
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
        },//end of reader
        writer:
        {
            type:'json',
            root:'records',
        },//End of writer

    }//end of proxy
});
```

2) Here is my some controller file code

```
var userObject = Ext.ModelManager.create(
        {
            firstName:record.get('firstName'),
            password:record.get('password'),

        },'ab.model.sn.UserModel');


userObject.save({    
    success: function(record, operation) 
    {
        console.log("registration successssssssssss  "+record.get('userId'));
    },//End of success function
    failure: function(record, operation) 
    {
        console.log("Inside failure functionnnnn");
    },//End of failure function
    callback: function(record, operation)
    {
        console.log("Inside callback functionnnnnn");   
    }//End of callback function
});// End of check save function
```

3) And data would be going in json format

```
{"records":{"userId":"","firstName":"ram","middleName":"","lastName":"","languageId":"","primaryEmail":"","birthDate":"","password":"sham","securityQuestionId":"","securityQuestionAnswer":"","isMale":"","creationTime":"","ipAddress":"","confirmationCode":"","userStatusId":"","id":null}}
```

4) But I want to send only firstName and password.I dont want send all fields. how can I send the data to server side.

I want json in this format

```
{"records":{"firstName":"ram","password":"sham"}}
```

please give me some suggestions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to overwrite the getRecordData function of the writer. Like this.

```
 writer:
            {
                type:'json',
                root:'records',
                getRecordData: function (record) { return {"firstName" :record.data.firstName,"password": record.data.password}; },
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

nscrob's answer has less coding so it may be preferred, but there is also a [built-in config](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-persist) for this on the model: `persist: false`. It keeps the model field from being sent to the server side.

IMHO the model configs don't seem to get used as well as they should even in the sencha examples (or maybe because they are not used in the sencha examples). I think it also saves a miniscule amount of resources if you define the data types in the model as opposed to letting the client work it out, for example:

```
Ext.define('ab.model.sn.UserModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    //idproperty:'userId',//fields property first position pk.

    // using field type definitions and explicit persistance
    fields: [
        {name: 'userId',                type: 'int',    persist: false},
        {name: 'firstName',             type: 'string'},
        {name: 'middleName',            type: 'string', persist: false},
        {name: 'lastName',              type: 'string', persist: false},
        {name: 'languageId',            type: 'int',    persist: false},
        {name: 'primaryEmail',          type: 'string', persist: false},
        {name: 'birthDate',             type: 'date',   dateFormat: 'c', persist: false},
        {name: 'password',              type: 'string'},
        {name: 'securityQuestionId',    type: 'int',    persist: false},
        {name: 'securityQuestionAnswer', type: 'string',persist: false},
        {name: 'isMale',                type: 'bool',   persist: false},
        {name: 'creationTime',          type: 'date',   dateFormat: 'c', persist: false},
        {name: 'ipAddress',             type: 'string', persist: false},
        {name: 'confirmationCode',      type: 'string', persist: false},
        {name: 'userStatusId',          type: 'int',    persist: false}
    ],
    proxy:
    {
        type:'ajax',
            //type:'localstorage',
            //id:'users',
        api:
        {
            read:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
            create:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin122',
            update:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin123'
        },//end of api
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
        },//end of reader
        writer:
        {
            type:'json',
            root:'records',
        },//End of writer

    }//end of proxy
});
```

Like I said, there is some more coding but I thought I would throw this out there as the built-in handling for this scenario (instead of the override). You could also drop the field type definitions if you wanted, they aren't required to define the `persist` property.